# No such file or directory - git://github.com/rails/rails_upgrade.git (Errno::ENOENT)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-migrations

I was trying to migrate rails app from 2.3.8 to 3.2. I found rails_upgrade plugin appropriate for migration task. But something is stopping me and I have no idea about it.

Also tried cloning the same plugin using ssh but rake task of plugin not building up.

```
    ruby script/plugin install git://github.com/rails/rails_upgrade.git "git://github.com/rails/rails_upgrade.git"

       /home/chitrank/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p374/lib/ruby/1.8/open-uri.rb:35:in `initialize': No such file or directory - git://github.com/rails/rails_upgrade.git (Errno::ENOENT)
       from /home/chitrank/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p374/lib/ruby/1.8/open-uri.rb:35:in `open_uri_original_open'
       from /home/chitrank/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p374/lib/ruby/1.8/open-uri.rb:35:in `open'
       from ./script/../config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/commands/plugin.rb:863:in `fetch_dir'
       from ./script/../config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/commands/plugin.rb:857:in `fetch'
       from ./script/../config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/commands/plugin.rb:856:in `each'
       from ./script/../config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/commands/plugin.rb:856:in `fetch'
       from ./script/../config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/commands/plugin.rb:219:in `install_using_http'
       from ./script/../config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/commands/plugin.rb:169:in `send'
       from ./script/../config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/commands/plugin.rb:169:in `install'
       from ./script/../config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/commands/plugin.rb:734:in `parse!'
       from ./script/../config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/commands/plugin.rb:732:in `each'
       from ./script/../config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/commands/plugin.rb:732:in `parse!'
       from ./script/../config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/commands/plugin.rb:447:in `parse!'
       from ./script/../config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/commands/plugin.rb:463:in `parse!'
       from ./script/../config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/commands/plugin.rb:871
       from script/plugin:3:in `require'
       from script/plugin:3
```

Can anyone help me over this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the HTTPS URL instead:

```
https://github.com/rails/rails_upgrade.git
```

Comment: I already tried, throwing another issue /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p374/lib/ruby/1.8/open-uri.rb:277:in `open_http': 404 Not Found (OpenURI::HTTPError)

Comment: Can you open the url on the command line (using curl or other program)? Make you don't have any environment variable like HTTP_PROXY messing arround.